# Don't you find this ridiculous?

Tags: discussion

I know that when you have rules then you should abide them and make sure everyone does too. But look at this screenshot and tell me if it doesn't make you laugh.

[image]

Comment: Yes :D indeed. Love computers and their automated way of working.

Comment: I blame the avatar. The system is just trying us to protect us from your evil.

Comment: Oh look, its me! 2x! Wow!

Comment: Oh w8... Why is there an arrow pointing at me??? (_secretly adds yohbs to the *must destroy* list_)